# Call .py file from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv, python-3.x, xlwings

I have a UserForm with a button called PRODRLIST and when you click it is supposed to sort My Product.csv and save its output as My Product.grouped.csv. I can run the Python code in IDLE and it works, but when I define a function (Sort_File()) I cannot get it to work. I'm still new to Python so I'm assuming it is something simple.

Excel VBA code to launch Python program:

```
Private Sub PRODRLIST_Click()
RunPython ("import SortProduct; SortProduct.Sort_File()")
End Sub
```

Python code to sort .csv file:

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
# file group_by_trailing_py2.py
import os
import csv
from itertools import groupby

DELIM=';'
IN_FILENAME = 'My Product.csv'
OUT_FILENAME = 'My Product.grouped.csv'


keyfunc = lambda row: row[1:]

with open(IN_FILENAME) as csv_file:
    rows = sorted(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM), key=keyfunc)

it = map(lambda t: [", ".join(v[0].strip() for v in t[1]) + " "] + t[0],
        groupby(rows, key=keyfunc))

with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=DELIM)  
for row in it:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Maybe I have to define a few more things or it's my indentation?

Comment: Why don't you paste the code with your `Sort_File` function?

Comment: @ Felix Zumstein I took it out of the code above but I had it right above keyfunc = lambda row:row[1:] and everything was indented after that. Im not sure how to make the above a function and call it from excel. In short the above is what i would like to be my Sort_File function. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well in case that `group_by_trailing_py2.py` is what your file is called, then you need to `import group_by_trailing_py2` and not `SortProduct`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub PRODRLIST_Click()
    Dim pyPrgm As String, pyScript As String
    pyPrgm = "C:\Python33\python.exe " 
'---- Space should be there after python 'exe path
    pyScript = "C:\Python33\MyScripts\sort.py" ' File path
    Call Shell(pyPrgm & pyScript, vbMaximizedFocus)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I put this code in with my button and it runs python. The only problem is it does not create the My Product.grouped.csv file. When i run the file in idle it creates the file so i know that part works. What am i missing.

Comment: I could nt find the full paths of the Csv files. What it "import SortProduct" mean ? is it possible to give within the python code. But I am not sure of the solution.

Comment: import SortProduct calls the .py file and the second part runs the function within SortProduct.  I tried defining the function before but was unable to get it to work. With your method of calling python i wouldnt need to define a function.